# xpath expression that omits unwanted part of returned text

Tags: html, regex, parsing, xpath

Assume you have used `htmlTreeParse()` to obtain this snippet of XML code:

```
   <div class="right_location">
      <h3>Office Locations</h3>
      <div class="right_location_in">
          <h4>
             <a href="/?t=10&L=234&format=XML&p=5406">Akron Office</a>
          <h4>
          <address>
          <address>
  </div>
  <div class="right_location_in">
         <h4>
            <a href="/?t=10&L=235&format=XML&p=5406">Cleveland Office</a>
```

There are an unknown number of offices following but this expression returns them.  All of them append " Office".

```
xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@class ='right_location']//a", xmlValue, trim = TRUE)
[1] "Akron Office"
```

How can I exclude the unneeded "Office" from each one?  I think I can't use the negative of `contains()` because the expression won't match.  Perhaps `text()` has a capability to omit designated text?

The answer of substring-befor() is good, but I need to have it operate for each location, not just the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The following XPath will return "Akron" from your XML:**

```
substring-before(//div[@class ='right_location']//a[1], ' Office')
```

**Notes:**

1. Use `a[1]` to select the first of possibly multiple `a`'s.
2. Use `substring-before` to prune off `' Office'`.
3. **Processing each matching `a` is typically done outside of XPath** itself (in XSLT or Python or other hosting language from which an XPath library is called for selection), **but if you're using XPath 2.0**, you might consider (a) using a [**for expression**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-for-expressions), (b) using Mathias Müller's suggestion of [**tokenize()**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize) with "Office" as the delimiter, or (c) [**replace()**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-replace)'ing "Office" with nothing if just want to get back "Akron Cleveland" without " Office".

Comment: Excellent, because I have never used substring-before().  In the actual site, there are two other cities after Akron.  The //a picks them all up if I leave off substring-before() but they all have "Office" after them.  How do I extract those cities also, sans "Office"?

Comment: You mean the actual input text is `Akron Office Another Office Yetanother Office`? You could tokenize the string, using "Office" as the delimiter.

Comment: @lawyeR, the answered XPath provides access to the first such `a` via the `[1]` construct as an example; the second such `a` would be `a[2]` and so on.  Typically, you'd iterate and handle each per your app's requirements.

Comment: @kjhughes: sorry to be an ignoramus, but is there something like //a[1:length(a)]?  or some way to indicate "strip 'Office' from all matches?  I am running searches on scores of sites and don't know how to iterate programmatically to increase the number in brackets -- I don't want to hard code it.

Comment: @lawyeR, you're fine, but please clarify what string exactly you would like the XPath expression to return if you're not going to process the results further with XSLT, Python, etc?

Comment: @kjhughes: I edited the question to show that I need to remove the Office from all matches, not just the first.  Eventually all the returned matches (from scores of other sites also) will be cleaned up with R (mostly regexing the city names) but if I can have the xpath output cleaner, even better.  Thank you for your time, talent, and thoughts.